# Blocking a sub directory with .htaccess file in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

Disclaimer: I have little to no knowledge of Apache, all the information posted here was pieced together from Google search results only, within 1 night.

--

I can't seem to get .htaccess to block only the sub-directories of my domain, could someone please help me?

My root domain: http://domain.com (/home/username/domain/)

The directory I'm trying to block is /home/username/domain/files/

In the /domain/ directory, I have modified the .htaccess file accordingly:

```
# Password Protect Directories #
AuthName "You shall not pass!"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/username/domain/files.htpasswd
require valid-user
# END Password Protect Directories #
```

The problem is, this seems to password protect my root directory as well as the sub-directory specified.

--

I've tried moving this .htaccess file entry into a separate .htaccess file in the /domain/files/ directory, but then this doesn't work at all, nothing is password protected.

I'm not quite sure what I'm supposed to be doing here, I've read dozens of tutorials online, but none seem to help me beyond password protecting my entire root directory.

--

Can someone please explain to me how I can block multiple sub-directories only?

```
/domain/files/
/domain/software/
/domain/pictures/
```

etc...

Thanks!

--

Alternately, if anyone knows a better way to accomplish this, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There really is nothing to the authentication. You need to put the code in the .htaccess file in the sub-directory you want to protect. Also I would not put my password file in a publicly accessible  location. Put it outside the root like in your home folder. So this code should go in your files folder.

```
# Password Protect Directories #
AuthName "You shall not pass!"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/username/.htpasswd
require valid-user
# END Password Protect Directories #
```

Make sure apache can read your .htpasswd file and the correct ownership and permissions. *Also try and clear your browser cache to test. I've seen that many times that it appears to not work until I clear the cache and then I get the prompt.*